# Dotfuscator Professional edition string encryption not working

Tags: obfuscation, dotfuscator

I use Dotfuscator Professional edition and did write very simple .NET app :

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello");
    }
}
```

I want to obfuse all strings in code, according current manual

https://www.preemptive.com/blog/article/1004-encrypting-string-constants-with-dotfuscator/107-support-corner

[image]

After all manipulations I still can see my string in dotPeek.

[image]

Where I made error ?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't enabled String Encryption itself. In your first image, "Disable String Encryption" is set to "Yes". Set it to "No". Then, on the String Encryption tab, browse your assembly's code and check the box next to any methods whose strings you want to encrypt.

(I work on the Dotfuscator team. I should note that, if you're using Dotfuscator Professional, then you have access to our [support team](https://www.preemptive.com/contact/supportrequestform), if you need further assistance.)